# What makes a program (in)compatible on 32/64 bit platforms?

Tags: desktop-development

Let's say I am developing a program for Windows. What are some things I can / can't do if I want it to be usable for 32 / 64 bit platforms?

Comment: This is to some degree programming language dependend, and it is probably too broad. Moreover, is this a hypothetical question, or do you have a specific program in mind you are going to write?

Answer (score 3):

My thoughts on this

- 32-bit applications can run on 64-bit windows but not vice-versa.
- 32-bit applications running on 64-bit windows by default see a "virtual" view of the filesystem and registry. This can get rather confusing sometimes.
- If your application uses a custom driver then that driver will need to have 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the driver. 64-bit windows is far more restrictive about driver-signing than 32-bit was.
- I am aware of at least one set of APIs* that is broken for 32-bit applications on 64-bit windows. If you run into such an API you may need to make seperate 32-bit and 64-bit builds of your application.
- In general test early and often on all supported platforms. It's easier to work arround a quirk you discover (whether related to version or number of bits) when you are first developing a feature than it is to have to deal with it later.

* The one i'm aware of is the "advanced firewall" COM API used to reconfigure the firewall on windows 7, but I expect if there is one such API broken there are others.

Comment: Often 64-bit apps cannot use 32-bit libs (and vice versa). You can avoid 32/64-bit problems if you develop code for virtual machines (i.e. java or c#)

Comment: @k3b but then you just push the question to "what are the incompatibilities between this .Net machine and this JVM machine both running on this Intel machine" </devils advocate>

Answer (score 0):

> What are some things I can / can't do if I want it to be usable for 32
>   / 64 bit platforms?

Everything @Peter Green said is right. Most of time, programs will be able to run on both 32bits / 64bits. Here are some other pitfalls:

- using a library which runs *only* on either is the most common constraint
- doing some funky stuff with pointer arithmetic can easely backfire because of a wrong assumption in a pointer's size (for c++ folks)
- programs using more than 4Gb memory require 64bit
- doing some very low-level OS/drivers stuff